# Violation of User Data policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

How can I submit the update, I already submitted my app 2 times. But then my website was not up(link was expired). Now I have to make a privacy policy page for this app? or should i simply give the URL of my site. OR WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?

> Issue: Violation of User Data policy and section 4.8 of the Developer
>   Distribution Agreement
>
> You must be transparent in how you handle user data (e.g., information
>   provided by a user, collected about a user, and collected about a
>   user’s use of the app or device), including by disclosing the
>   collection, use, and sharing of the data, and you must limit use of
>   the data to the description in the disclosure.
>
> Per section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement: “You agree
>   that if You make Your Products available through Google Play, You will
>   protect the privacy and legal rights of users. If the users provide
>   You with, or Your Product accesses or uses, usernames, passwords, or
>   other login information or personal information, You agree to make the
>   users aware that the information will be available to Your Product,
>   and You agree to provide legally adequate privacy notice and
>   protection for those users.”
>
> Please note that any antivirus or security app must include a Privacy
>   Policy that, together with any in-app disclosures, explains what user
>   data your app collects and transmits, how it’s used, and the types of
>   parties with whom it’s shared.
>
> Submit your app for another review
>
> Read through the User Data policy and section 4.8 of the Developer
>   Distribution Agreement for more details. Add a privacy policy to your
>   store listing: Sign in to your Play Console Select your app. Select
>   Store presence > Store listing. Under "Privacy Policy," enter the URL
>   where you have the privacy policy hosted online. Submit the update to
>   your app. Make sure that your app is compliant with all other
>   Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if
>   there are further policy violations. If you’ve reviewed the policy and
>   feel our decision may have been in error, please reach out to our
>   policy support team. One of my colleagues will get back to you within
>   2 business days.

In the app i have this permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about the policies of an external application store.

Answer (score 0):

All android apps are required to have a Privacy Policy. Make this page in your website and update it in developer console

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that any antivirus or security app must include a Privacy Policy that, together with any in-app disclosures, explains what user data your app collects and transmits, how it’s used, and the types of parties with whom it’s shared.

Specifically taking note on this section of the rejection, here are my suggestions:

1. Ensure you have a privacy policy that outlines how user data is collected and used. There are privacy policy generators that you can use.
2. Based on the message they sent you, it also sounds like you don't have any prompts detailing *to the user* what data is being collected and how it's being used. If this is the cause for rejection, I suggest looking over [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview) and paying close attention to the **Dangerous Permissions** section.
3. Furthermore, as the message states, look over the [User Data](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/) policy and section 4.8 of the [developer agreement](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html).

The legalities of deploying an app can sometimes be complex, so be sure to carefully read the rules and guidelines. Reaching out to the policy support team might be able to provide more clarity to your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

In privacy policy page includes:

- User information you are collecting.
- Use of that information.
- Let users know that you are sharing their information to anyone or not.

That is it. Hope it helps.